# How can Selenium RC process dynamic rows?

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I have a table similar to the following:

Part #          
    Price     
    Status
  
  
  
    1st Part #   
    $1.00   
    OK
  
  
  
    2nd Part #  
    $2.00   
    Discontinued
  
  
  
    Nth Part #   
    $N.00   
    Reordered

My java code will be looking for the status of "Nth Part #" where I have no idea how big the table is, how many columns it has, and no idea what N is (until run time).  In Ruby/WATIR, I would have used the table's id to grab it's HTML, and then used Ruby to iterate over the rows until the part # matched, and then check that row's corresponding status in the Status column (whichever column that might be, but it's set in the hd header's row).

Selenium's standard table lookup function selenium.getTable("table.1.2") only works for static tables that contain the same contents for each test. The overkill selenium.get_html_source is a waste since selenium knows how to find the table already, plus then I have to parse the entire web page.

Any ideas on how I can grab the html of the table, and what would be the best way to iterate over the rows and/or columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to use `getTable` like this

```
selenium.getTable("table." + (1 + n) + ".3")
```

to get the "Status" cell for the `n`th row if you know what `n` will be at runtime.

If you are trying to iterate over all of the rows in the table, you could do something like this

```
try {
    for(int n = 1; true; n++) {
         String cellContents = selenium.getTable("table." + n + ".3");
         //do something with n
    }
}
catch {
    //handle end of table
}
```

or, alternatively

```
final int rowCount = (int)selenium.getXPathCount("id('table')/tbody/tr");
for(int n = 1; n < rowCount; n++) {
    String cellContents = selenium.getTable("table." + n + ".3");
}
```

Remember that in `getTable(locator.row.column)`, `row` and `column` start at 1.

Comment: @Tihamer Toth-Feijel anything specific that I can try to help you with?

Comment: A few caveats, though.  In the expression: selenium.getTable("table." + n + ".3"); 
the "table." is the id of the table; if it doesn't have an id, or if you don't know it, then it won't work. What will? 
Second, using exception failures to count rows (and columns) seems rather... iffy. 
It appears that getXpathCount() should get it, but I had a very difficult time with it.  The following finally worked:  
int rows =  
  selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='mytable']//tr").intValue();  
columns =  
 selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='mytable']//tr[2]//td").intValue();

Comment: The Selenium documentation says that the format is `tableLocator.row.column` which would seem to indicate that you can use any location strategy (xpath, css, etc) for `tableLocator`.

Comment: You wrote:
  "Remember that in getTable(locator.row.column), row and column start at 1."
Not on my version (I'm using 2.0b3). Row 0 gets me the topmost row (the header), while column 0 gets me the leftmost column.
Maybe it's the way I set it up.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Tihamer Toth-Fejel The documentation I was referring to was for selenium 1. Interesting to see that they've changed it for selenium 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but I solved a similar problem by assigning the unique id (part number it sounds like in your case) to be the html id of the `tr`.  Then I used the Selenium xpath locators to get the row and columns I needed for my test.

Comment: Thanks, Wesley.  I think I got it working the way I want. Using xpath seems the way to go to avoid exception-based counting, but xpath is not quite what I call a programming language. I'm going through the w3schools tutorial now.  Guess it's learning on the job.  :-)